# Automatically generate keys for a map in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, maps

I have a Class that creates objects and stores them into a map with integer keys
So if the user is creating a new object , the default first key is 100 and then if the user decides to make more then it increments by 1 (i.e. 101, 102, etc). How would I automate this process?

For example, say the class is creating vector of string objects that contain the names of a classroom.

```
std::map<int, vector<string>> classrooms;
```

So then the first time the user creates an instance, the first one will be accessed by integer key 100, but then how would I make it increment by 1 if the user wants to add in more. (Assume the int main is running in a while loop that allows interactive commands to keep on creating more classrooms)

Comment: Perhaps you could use a variable to store the number and add one to that variable each time?

Comment: Why dont you store them in a `std::vector`? If you need to have access to the `100+N-elemet` you can write a simple getter function.

Comment: What's the use of the `vector<string>`?  Does a classroom have more than one name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a key generator class with overloaded `operator ()` to generate key incremental unique key by each call, something like this :

```
#include <map>

class keyGen
{
public:
    keyGen(int x): key(x) {}
    int operator()(int x = 1)  { 
        return (key += x);
    }
private:
    int key;
};

class someClass
{
private:
    std::map<int, std::string> dataMap;
    keyGen kg;

public:
    someClass(): kg(0) {};
    void createFoo(std::string foo)
    {
        dataMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(kg(), foo));
    }
    void createBar(std::string bar)
    {
        dataMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(kg(), bar));
    }

};

int main()
{
    someClass sc;
    sc.createFoo("foo"); //sc::dataMap == [1, "foo"]
    sc.createBar("bar"); //sc::dataMap == [2, "bar"]
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i dont really get the point of the `keyGen`. You would get the same if you just used a bare `int` and `m.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(++counter, "foo"));`

Comment: @user463035818 You are correct, but this this is what OP asked, isn't it?

Comment: hm, yes you are right. Actually I didnt really understand what OP asked for ;)

Comment: @user463035818 I guessed OP wants a dynamic way to generate keys, something maybe more complicate than `++`. this is just a demo example but good thing is by one change in `operator ()` definition it can be customized.

Comment: yes i got your point, I would just encapsulate the map to avoid misuse as in `m[3] = ....` or the like. However, if OP combines our answers they will get both

Comment: Yep I need a dynamic way to store the keys 
The int main() would be interactive so like, the user could type like create 2 which signals the user wants to create a classroom with 2 students so then it the user types John and Sam and then it gives a message saying "classroom 100 created" and then say the user wants to create another classroom but this time with 3 kids, so then they do create 3 and this creates ID 101 etc. and if user wants to quit they type quit.

Comment: There would be other options like if the user wants to fetch the contents or manipulate the contents of a specific classroom they'd need access to that key but thats not really this question though haha

Comment: What if the insertions were done in a  method in the class which creates the string objects? instead of manually through main(), wouldn't it have to check if the key exists first before storing the string into map

Comment: i.e. insert_string(std::string); was put inside the class as well as a separate method to show the contents of the map. 
and then int main() took user inputs until the user chooses to stop via a quit command and says create Foo ----> so this creates Foo assigned to ID 1 , and then user says create Bar ----> this would rerun the method but wouldn't know ID 1 already exists and proceed to overwrite Foo, so if the user types show (command to show contents of the map) then it'd only show 1: Bar , instead 1: Foo, 2: Bar

Comment: @Hamed, yeah , create Foo and create Bar are just user inputs, where Foo and Bar are passed into a method that inserts it into the map. This method is declared in the class. Edit; Oh I misread, the map insertion method would be declared in a separate class

Comment: @Hamed I got it work however when I go to check my map it only stored Foo instead of both Foo and Bar

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to store object and store them in the map, but your example has a map of vectors of strings, so to stay with that example you could write a container that manages creation of classrooms and the map:

```
struct classroom_collection {
        typedef std::vector<std::string>> classroom_type;
        classroom_type& create_classroom();
        //... more ... eg get_class_room(size_t index);
    private:
        std::map<size_t,classroom_t> classrooms;
};
```

The `create_classroom` would create a `classroom`, add it to the map and return a reference to it. More generic this would look like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct X_collection {
        X& create_X();
    private:
        std::map<size_t,X> data;
};
```

and if `classroom` is your custom class (not just a vector of strings) it should have a private constructor and be a friend of the collection such that the only way to create a `classroom` would be via the `classroom_collection`.